# HTML date value is empty

Tags: html, angular

I bring the user birthdays from the database and reflect them on the calendar. The code part and the screenshot are as follows.
When I say save the birthday I brought directly, it saves it blank. But it seems to be selected in the calendar because I brought it from the database. Can you help me why is this happening?

```
<input type="date" nbInput fullWidth fieldSize="small"
 [value]="person.date| date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"
formControlName="date">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you are using reactive forms you should update the form values in a reactive manner. Using `patchValue` instead of `[value]`.

```
this.form.patchValue({
    date: this.person.date
})
```

This is happening because you are updating the input's "value" but not your internal form representation. So when you save the birthday directly it will save whatever value you initialised the form field with. (In this case a blank string by the sounds of it)